# Sublime Text LiveReload Is Not Working

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using `Sublime Text` editor for web development using HTML. I have installed packages for `LiveReload` in to my sublime editor they installed perfectly but still pages are not reloading automatically.
I have completely followed following article

[How do I install LiveReload on Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886011/how-do-i-install-livereload-sublime-text-3)

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

With the file(s) active that you want to trigger the LiveReload event, launch the Command Palette and choose *“Live Reload: Enable/disable plug-ins”*, then choose an event (e.g. *“Enable: Simple Reload”* to reload whenever the file is saved.)