# What could be the reason LiveReload extension works on Mozilla, but not on Chrome or Brave?

Tags: google-chrome, sublimetext3, mozilla, livereload

The icon is there, but it wont activate when clicked. I'm using Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work with every browser under the sun is that every browser's API is different. It does work with Chrome and Safari - there is a link to [extensions](http://livereload.com/extensions/) right there in the README.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I meant that chrome extension doesn't work

Comment: Looking at the Chrome extension page, it says it was last updated in 2015, so there's a very good chance that the Chrome API has changed enough that the extension doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This answer directly helped me:

[How do I install LiveReload on Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886011/how-do-i-install-livereload-on-sublime-text-3#33409684)

I was able to address this issue by updating LiveReload's settings from within **Sublime Text 3** via:

`Preferences > Package Settings > LiveReload > Settings - Default`

and updating:

```
    {
        "enabled_plugins": []
    }
```

to:

```
    {
        "enabled_plugins": [
            "SimpleReloadPlugin",
            "SimpleRefresh"]
    }
```